# Why am I unreachable?

Tags: monerod, blockchain

I'm certain the forwarded port of 18081, 18089, 18080 are forwarded to the machine and i've completely disabled windows firewall. Is this my ISP blocking this port?

```
C:\Users\monero-gui-v0.17.2.1>monerod.exe --public-node --restricted-rpc
2021-05-02 22:26:03.387 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.2.0-release)
2021-05-02 22:26:03.389 W --public-node is enabled, but RPC server 127.0.0.1:18081 may be unreachable from outside, please check RPC server bind address
2021-05-02 22:26:03.390 I Initializing cryptonote protocol...
2021-05-02 22:26:03.391 I Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
2021-05-02 22:26:03.393 I Initializing core...
2021-05-02 22:26:03.395 I Loading blockchain from folder C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb ...
2021-05-02 22:26:03.560 I Loading checkpoints
2021-05-02 22:26:03.561 I Core initialized OK
2021-05-02 22:26:03.562 I Initializing p2p server...
2021-05-02 22:26:03.579 I p2p server initialized OK
2021-05-02 22:26:03.579 I Initializing core RPC server...
2021-05-02 22:26:03.580 I Binding on 127.0.0.1 (IPv4):18081
2021-05-02 22:26:05.781 I core RPC server initialized OK on port: 18081
2021-05-02 22:26:05.791 I Starting core RPC server...
2021-05-02 22:26:05.792 I core RPC server started ok
2021-05-02 22:26:05.793 I Public RPC port 18081 will be advertised to other peers over P2P
2021-05-02 22:26:05.794 I Starting p2p net loop...
```

Comment: In future, please use the formatting buttons in the editor. Otherwise things like this log output are unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

If you read your logs:

> W --public-node is enabled, but RPC server 127.0.0.1:18081 may be unreachable from outside, please check RPC server bind address

Then check the `monerod --help` output:

```
--rpc-bind-ip arg (=127.0.0.1)             Specify IP to bind RPC server
--rpc-restricted-bind-ip arg (=127.0.0.1)  Specify IP to bind restricted RPC server
--confirm-external-bind                    Confirm rpc-bind-ip value is NOT a loopback (local) IP
```

So to bind all interfaces (which includes external), use `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`, and use `--confirm-external-bind` to state you know what you're doing.